# Массив вхождений

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Допустим у нас есть строка, типа:

```
 "{a}{b}{c}

            {e}       {g} {l}"
```

и есть регулярка:

```
 /{([^\0]+)?}/gim
```

Как получить массив `([^\0]+)` значений?

Грубо говоря

```
str.replace(/{([^\0])+?}/gim, '$1') // нужен массив $1 значений
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
var arr = [];
while( var tmp = re.exec( str ) ){
  arr.push( tmp );
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
re = /(?:{)[^{}]*(?:})/gmi;
arr = str.match(re);
```

С избавлением от скобок, но не знаю насколько корректно:

```
re = /(?!{)[^{}]+(?=})/gmi;
arr = str.match(re);
```

Вариант 3.1:

```
str = "{a}{b}{c}\n\n\n            {e}       {g} {l}";
str += '{';
str = str.replace( /{([^}]+)}[^{}]*?(?={)/gm, "$1\v" );
arr = str.slice( 0, str.length - 1 ).split("\v");
```

Вариант 3.2:

```
str = '}' + str + '{';
str = str.replace( /}[^{}]*{/gm, "\v" );
arr = str.slice( 1, str.length - 1 ).split("\v");
```

Тест скорости:

```
test = function (){
  var str_or = "{a}{b}{c}\n\n\n            {e}       {g} {l}",
      re, str, tmp, arr, i, max = 1000;

  arr = [];
  for ( i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ){
    arr.push( str_or );
  }
  str_or = arr.join('')

  str = str_or;
  re = /{([^{}]+)}/gmi;
  console.time('test 1');
  for( i = 0; i < max; i++ ){
    arr = [];
    while( tmp = re.exec( str ) ){
      arr.push( tmp[1] );
    }
  }
  console.timeEnd('test 1');

  str = str_or;
  re = /(?!{)[^{}]+(?=})/gmi;
  console.time('test 2');
  for( i = 0; i < max; i++ ){
    arr = str.match(re);
  }
  console.timeEnd('test 2');

  re = /{([^}]+)}[^{}]*?(?={)/gm;
  console.time('test 3');
  for( i = 0; i < max; i++ ){
    str = str_or + '{';
    str = str.replace( re, "$1\v" );
    arr = str.slice( 0, str.length - 1 ).split("\v");
  }
  console.timeEnd('test 3');

  re = /}[^{}]*{/gmi;
  console.time('test 4');
  for( i = 0; i < max; i++ ){
    str = '}' + str_or + '{';
    str = str.replace( re, "\v" );
    arr = str.slice( 1, str.length - 1 ).split("\v");
  }
  console.timeEnd('test 4');
}

test();
```

При строке 41 * 10^6 символов и 1 итерации:

```
test 1: 2487ms
test 2: 2680ms
test 3: 2992ms
test 4: 2393ms
```

При строке 41 * 10^4 символов и 1000 итераций:

```
test 1: 10162ms
test 2: 26095ms
test 3: 23798ms
test 4: 22280ms
```

Comment: А по производительности как этот вариант? Не лучше ли собрать все совпадения и просто заменить '{' и '}' на ''?

В данном случае мне нужна высокая производительность, готов к хакам и велосипедам, даже (если критично) - рассмотрю варианты на С++ etc.

Comment: Строка:

     "{a}{b}{c}

                {e}       {g} {l}"



     console.log(str.match(re));
     // -> [ '{a}', '{b}', '{c}', '{e}', '{g}', '{l}' ]
     //     Мне же нужно
     // -> [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'l' ]

Первый пример работает, правда надо изменить `arr.push( tmp );` на `arr.push( tmp[1] )`

Но я как-то не уверен в производительности этого варианта( не "излишен" ли он? )

Comment: массив без скобок, максимально "правильно" и просто, как нибудь я и сам написал бы

Как тестить я в курсе, спс

Вы бы вопрос внимательнее почитали, я же не просто так написал

     //нужен массив $1 значений

Comment: спасиб за тесты, меня полностью устраивает первый вариант и читабельностью и скоростью

Но ты немного не ту задачу решаешь =)

Comment: Исправил) Была ошибка в RE... Обновил результаты....

Сложно сказать есть-ли абсолютный победитель, т.к. не ясно как формируется скорость)

Answer (score 0):

[[@timka_s](/users/1192/timka_s)](/users/1192/timka_s) - судя по всему ты меня просто не совсем правильно понял.
Ну да не суть - вот решение:

```
// str - string with {someValue} parts 
function getClearOccurrence(str) {
    var preg = /{([^\0]+)?}/gim;
    var matches = []
    while( tmp = preg.exec( str ) ){
        matches.push( tmp[1] );
    }
    return matches;
    // returns values array
}
```

Ну и пример

```
  var str = "{a} some text {b}  some text  {c}{e}{g}  sdsds  {l}";
  // функция, при передаче подобной строки длиною > 1к строчек
  // отработала за 0.025 - меня это устраивает

  var matches = getClearOccurrence(str);
  console.log(matches); // -> [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'l' ];
```

Думал что решение недостаточно быстрое - ошибся, работает замечательно

Comment: @timka_s - все-равно большое спасибо, без `preg.exec` я бы это не написал =)